# Rename many columns header with function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to rename the header for a DataFrame. My method was as shown below:
[image]

I was thinking if i would like to rename 100 columns, this wasn't practical.
Is there any method to do header rename ?

Maybe by function ?
Please guide me if u have solution, thankssss.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for `Unnamed:`  substring and then for `Unit 1-17` value, `^` is for start of string and `$` is for end of string for prevent replace substring like `Unit 1-170`:

```
df.columns = (df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed:\s+', 'Unit 1-')
                        .str.replace('^Unit 1-17$','Judgement'))
```

Or us custom function for extract number after `Unnamed` and add substring if not `17`:

```
import re

def f(x):
    match = re.search('Unnamed:\s+(\d+)', x)
    if match:
        num = match.group(1)
        return 'Unit 1-'+ num if num != '17' else 'Judgement'
    else:
        return x

df = df.rename(columns=f)
```